# htaccess - do not rewrite in this case

Tags: .htaccess

My access file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

But I have a directory called facebook that I want to access as usuall through the URL http://mysite.com/facebook. What do I need to add to the above so that it ignores (does not rewrite) this directory?

Comment: Can you explain why you need RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] AND
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L] ? RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d should allow normal directory traversal, since that turns off rewriting for directories that exist.

Comment: I don't understand it myself - it is the standard htaccess file for Zend Framework.

Comment: Do you have any routes that use "facebook" as the url? Think about what might be causing the problem. It could also be permissions on the directory.

Comment: The Zend routing expects the first item after the domain to be the name of the controller, so http://mysite.com/facebook would route to a controller called facebookController. This is infact what is happening and the error that is reported is "missing controller facebook". So the htacess is doing it's job... I just don't want it to work with this directory.

Comment: That would actually imply that the .htaccess *isn't* doing its job because RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d is supposed to allow you to view directories. I'll do some testing and submit an answer.

Comment: Which version of Apache are you running?

Comment: My version of Apache is 2.2.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/facebook
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Get 500 error with that, even after changing Rewrute to Rewrite.

Comment: @Owen Try without a space after `!`

Comment: @LazyOne - well that does not 500 error now, but it makes no difference. The request still goes through to index.php/facebook.

Comment: @Owen Try replacing `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` by `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` -- I've answered few questions here where this helped (unsure why -- must be some specific setup). Otherwise -- add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/facebook` before your LAST line (before `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`) -- not like Death did (move that line 1 position down).

Comment: Thanks guys, just moving the condition to the penultimate line made things work :-)