# Zend Framework - do not treat /public/directory as a controller

Tags: zend-framework

Is it possible to request a directory over http in the Zend /public/ directory without it being treated as a controller?

Eg, I have a directory, /public/facebook/ that contains facebook app data but Zend is (as default expected behaviour) giving "facebook controller missing" error when I request http://mysite.com/facebook.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default RewriteRules provided with Zend are redirecting all requests to the Zend Framework Bootstrapper (index.php).

The best thing to do, IMHO, is to add an exception to this Rule. Then there's more than one way to do it. You could use RewriteCond (and for example avoid the general redirect for existing directory or files in /public). But you could maybe filter it in the RewriteRule expression as well. This is an example with exception in the RewritreRule, so withoutt RewriteCond:

```
RewriteRule !(public/facebook/(.*\.php))|(public/(.*\.pdf))|(externalauthent\.php)|(favicon.ico)|(images/(.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|png|bmp|JPG|JPEG|BMP|GIF|PNG)))|(css/(.*\.css))|(js/(.*\.*))$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: wow that's some rule! Is there an error in it... I just pasted it directly into my access file and got 500 error? I'm not really sure what that rule does but ultimately I want to be able to request http://mysite.com/facebook/app/index.php without Zend's controller issue.

Comment: So first try a simplier one `RewriteRule !(public/facebook/app/index\.php)|(facebook/app/index\.php)$ /index.php [L]` Here I used 2 versions of the parth, not sure of the right one, it means if the path is not one of what is listed (with or sign |) then redirect it to index.php

Comment: I don't know why but that also gave a 500 error. I found a solution that worked, and it is adding the following to the penultimate line of the standard Zend htaccess file: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/facebook

Answer (score 0):

If you have content in this url, ZF don't try to found facebook controller, You need add a folder named facebook, and a file index.php into this folder

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/public_directory_name
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Just replace 'public_directory_name' with the name of the directory you don't want Zend to treat as a controller.

Answered in a different worded question: [htaccess - do not rewrite in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572540/htaccess-do-not-rewrite-in-this-case)